# QgsSpatialIndex crash my deploy C++ QGIS custom application on windows

Tags: qgis, c++, windows, deployment

When I use the QgsSpatialIndex class, after leaving the method, my application crash. Looks like the object QgsSpatialIndex class works, it brings QgsFeatureId list, but from what I noticed something in the "destruction" of the object makes the application crash. I'm using Windows 7. I installed qgis with osgeo4w-setup-x86.

qgis-dev: 2.9.0-3

```
void MainWindow::addLayer(){
    QString myLayerPath         = "C:\\Users\\osgeos4w\\Documents\\desktop_gis_data";
    QString myLayerBaseName     = "world_borders";
    QString myProviderName      = "ogr";
    QgsVectorLayer * mypLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(myLayerPath, myLayerBaseName, myProviderName, true);
    QList<QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;
    QList<QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;
    if (mypLayer->isValid()) {
        qDebug("Layer is valid");
    } else {
        qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
        return;
    }
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(mypLayer, TRUE);
    myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(mypLayer));
    mpMapCanvas->setExtent(mypLayer->extent());
    mpMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);

    QgsSpatialIndex index(mypLayer->getFeatures());
    QgsPoint p = QgsPoint(-33.33,-5.97);
    QList<QgsFeatureId> featuiresIds = index.nearestNeighbor(p, 2);
    qDebug() << "fdis count = " << featuiresIds.count();
}
```

The output console is: "fdis count = 2"

it worked but crashes the application soon after the end of the method, and this only execute without crash if I comment the follow line:

```
QList<QgsFeatureId> featuiresIds = index.nearestNeighbor(p, 2);
qDebug() << "fdis count = " << featuiresIds.count();
```

If I execute the same code in the python conselo inside the QGIS Desktop 2.9.0, it works perfectly

Do anyone have any idea what might be happening?